# apply transformation to vector with index using template function

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I am trying to apply a transformation on a vector while also adding the index in the transformation function. I am using the following transformation function `transformWithIndex`. If I remove `idx` from `result.push_back(itransformationFunction(idx, element));` it works correctly.

> I understood that I have an extra argument. But I don't understand how
>   to modify the transformation function in order to handle the IDX.

---

```
// Example program That can be tested
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename Range, class TransformationFunction>
inline std::vector<typename std::result_of<TransformationFunction(typename Range::value_type)>::type>
transformWithIndex(const Range &iRange, const TransformationFunction &itransformationFunction) {
  std::vector<typename std::result_of<TransformationFunction(typename Range::value_type)>::type> result;
  int                                                                                            idx = 0;
  for (auto &&element : iRange) {
    result.push_back(itransformationFunction(idx, element));
    idx++;
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> source = {1, 2, 3};
   std::vector<int> result = transformWithIndex(source, [](int i) { return ++i; });

   return 0;
}
```

---

The errors are the following:

```
>  In instantiation of 'std::vector<typename
> std::result_of<TransformationFunction(typename
> Range::value_type)>::type> transformWithIndex(const Range&, const
> TransformationFunction&) [with Range = std::vector<int>;
> TransformationFunction = main()::<lambda(int)>; typename
> std::result_of<TransformationFunction(typename
> Range::value_type)>::type = int]': 21:82:   required from here 12:58:
> error: no match for call to '(const main()::<lambda(int)>) (int&,
> const int&)' 21:58: note: candidates are: 12:58: note: int (*)(int)
> <conversion> 12:58: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
> 21:65: note: main()::<lambda(int)> 21:65: note:   candidate expects 1
> argument, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `itransformationFunction(idx, element)` (2 arguments)
whereas your lambda once expect one.

Change call to something like:

```
transformWithIndex(source, [](int index, int &elem) { return index + 1; })
```

and your `result_of` should be fixed too to include index:

```
template <typename Range, class TransformationFunction>
std::vector<typename std::result_of<TransformationFunction(std::size_t, typename Range::value_type)>::type>
transformWithIndex(const Range &iRange, const TransformationFunction &itransformationFunction) {
  std::vector<typename std::result_of<TransformationFunction(std::size_t, typename Range::value_type)>::type> result;
  int                                                                                            idx = 0;
  for (auto &&element : iRange) {
    result.push_back(itransformationFunction(idx, element));
    idx++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

and `std::decay_t` should probably be applied to handle cases when functor return reference or const objects.

Comment: @HaniGotc: because all your `result_of` also need to change: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kfs953jtSdr17Gq3